# how to print values for an array in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a text box in my XIB named "txt" and a button named "next".
Now on the click of next button I want to print values of myArray.

```
NSArray *myArray
 myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"3",@"5",@"45",@"67",nil];
```

can anyone help me with this.

Comment: u want to print in the console?  or in the testfield...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray *myArray  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"3",@"5",@"45",@"67",nil];
-(IBAction)nextAction:(id)sender{

NSString *currentObj = txt.text;
int index = -1;

if(currentObj != nil&&[myArray containsObject:currentObj]){
index = [myArray indexOfObject:currentObj];
} 

index++;
if(index<myArray.count)
   txt.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];

}
```

Answer (score 13):

This will do

```
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.title = [myArray objectatindex:index];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *myArray myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"3",@"5",@"45",@"67",nil];
```

change it to

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"3",@"5",@"45",@"67",nil];
```

Otherwise you are doomed: D

Comment: this is not the solution to the question,write this in comment and also I guess that would be by mistake.

Comment: ok..ok...just saying..i was also thinking how doesn't the program already show any error..NSLog will suffice as a solution